# Split method and store

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to use the `split` method to get the last value, i.e. 0, from this string:

```
d = 'Alert|6317fe57-6787-4132-b40e-6d2863c921cb|0'
```

and store it a variable called `m`. I am using below code but for some reason it's failing:

```
import re
d = 'Alert|6317fe57-6787-4132-b40e-6d2863c921cb|0'
if re.split(('|')[-1], 'd') == 0:
    print 'ok'
```

I could not see `'ok'` being printed, although the `split` method should return `0`.

Comment: >>> import re
>>> d = 'Alert|6317fe57-6787-4132-b40e-6d2863c921cb|0'
>>> if re.split(('|')[-1], 'd') == 0:
...   print 'ok'
...
>>>
>>>

As above I could not see ok being printed although split function should return 0. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your regex is **completely broken**, as you would have discovered trivially if you'd bothered to test it at all:

```
>>> re.split(('|')[-1], 'd')
['d']  # I doubt this is what you expected...
```

In short:

- The `[-1]` is in the wrong place;
- You're using the string literal `'d'` not the identifier `d` (so the string you're trying to process isn't actually involved in this at all);
- The parentheses aren't actually part of the expression (and are completely redundant where they are, `('|')[-1] == '|'[-1]`) - note also that you only need them in the regex if you want the output to include the matches in the result; and
- The pipe character `|` has semantic meaning in regex, so must be escaped.

Fixing all of that:

```
>>> re.split(r'(\|)', d)
['Alert', '|', '6317fe57-6787-4132-b40e-6d2863c921cb', '|', '0']
>>> re.split(r'(\|)', d)[-1]
'0'
```

---

Even once you've fixed the regex, you're getting a *string*, `'0'`, which is never going to equal `0`:

```
>>> '0' == 0
False
```

Python is dynamically **but strongly** typed, so won't implicitly convert either argument for the comparison. You either need to explicitly convert the string to an integer:

```
>>> int('0') == 0
True
```

or compare to a string:

```
>>> '0' == '0'
True
```

---

However, there's really no need to use `re.split` for this; I would just use the standard string method [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> d.rsplit('|', 1)
['Alert|6317fe57-6787-4132-b40e-6d2863c921cb', '0']
>>> d.rsplit('|', 1)[1] == '0'
True
```

which minimises the number of split operations (and thus new string objects) required, or simply test whether [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) what I want:

```
>>> d.endswith('|0')
True
```

which will test at most two characters and is therefore even more efficient.

Comment: @VigneshKalai thanks! It started as *"you're comparing a string to an integer"* then spiralled out of control from there ;o)